# Is it in any way possible to verify heroku without the need of a credit card

Tags: heroku

I have this application on Heroku on which i would like to connect my custom domain to.
I saw on their site that it isn't possible to do this without the verification of my account with a credit card. I do not own a credit card, visa or mastercard. I only have a maestro/bancontact card (they do not supply me with the info needed to fill in the form).

Is there any way i could somehow add my domain to my heroku app?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to add a domain without adding a payment method. Adding a payment method makes your account a verified account and it also gives you 450+ dyno hours.

Payment methods:
*Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover and JCB credit cards are accepted. Debit cards are also accepted for Visa, MasterCard or JCB. We do not accept any other cards.*

You are never charged if you are on free dyno. While adding the card, a verification hold fee (1 unit in your country's currency is debited and credited back to your account in a day.)

**Additional Info:**

Once you add your domain, it will be served over HTTP only. For adding you own SSL certificate or using a shared SSL certificate by Heroku, your app needs to be on Hobby dyno costing $7.

Comment: Too bad i don't have any of those, but thanks for the info!